# Compiler doesn' see created bean

Tags: spring, javabeans, creation, sessionfactory

from few days I am trying to solve problem that occurs in my program, I tried many ways of solving, but nothing has worked. Here's the stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.caveofprogramming.spring.web.dao.UsersDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5077)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5591)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4097)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1545)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1555)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1555)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1523)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.caveofprogramming.spring.web.dao.UsersDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 26 more
```

Here's my UsersDao class:

```
package com.caveofprogramming.spring.web.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
@Component("usersDao")
public class UsersDao {

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource jdbc) {
        this.jdbc = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbc);
    }

    public Session session() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean create(User user) {

        MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();

        params.addValue("username", user.getUsername());
        params.addValue("password", passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        params.addValue("email", user.getEmail());
        params.addValue("name", user.getName());
        params.addValue("enabled", user.isEnabled());
        params.addValue("authority", user.getAuthority());

        return jdbc.update(
                "insert into users (username, name, password, email, enabled, authority) values (:username, :name, :password, :email, :enabled, :authority)",
                params) == 1;
    }

    public boolean exists(String username) {
        return jdbc.queryForObject("select count(*) from users where username=:username",
                new MapSqlParameterSource("username", username), Integer.class) > 0;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return session().createQuery("from User").list();
        // return jdbc.query("select * from users",
        // BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(User.class));
    }

}
```

Here's my dao-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.caveofprogramming.spring.web.dao">
    </context:component-scan>

    <beans profile="production">

        <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/spring" id="dataSource"
            expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        </jee:jndi-lookup>

        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        </bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven />

    </beans>

</beans>
```

And here's my datasource.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.caveofprogramming.spring.test">
    </context:component-scan>

    <beans profile="dev">
        <context:property-placeholder
            location="com/caveofprogramming/spring/web/test/config/jdbc.properties" />

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">

            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"></property>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>com.caveofprogramming.spring.web.dao</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        </bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven />

    </beans>


</beans>
```

Here's program structure:

[image: program structure]

Any ideas what is incorrect in code? I will be very grateful for any ideas, cause I've already lost many hours trying to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

The "sessionFactory" bean you have is a [factory for creating SessionFactory instances](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html). A Factory Factory, if you will. It doesn't implement the Hibernate SessionFactory interface directly.

Try adding another bean to your configuration that is `SessionFactory` obtained from this factory:

```
<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"
    factory-bean="sessionFactory"
    factory-method="newSessionFactory"/>
```

Comment: I've pasted that into my datasource.xml, but it's still the same error. Should I change anything else?

Comment: Maybe the datasource.xml file isn't getting included in your Spring context. How are you bootstrapping Spring? Are you trying to only load it during testing?